# struggling to understand how models and associations are saved in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, validation, associations

I'm new to ruby and rails and I'm wanting to following coding standards and conventions as best as possible, so I don't pick up any bad habits. I have two models: Course and Location. A course belongs_to a location, as a course can only have one location. A location has_many courses, as a location could be shared by more than one course.

When creating a course, a location may already exist that is found by its ID. Or the location may not yet exist, in which case a new location record must be created. My Course controller has the following create action.

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(params[:course])

  if params[:course][:location][:id].blank?
    @course.location = Location.create(params[:course][:location])
  else
    @course.location = Location.find_by_id(params[:course][:location][:id])
  end

  @course.save

  respond_with @course
end
```

Note that this is a REST API that only responds with JSON. The javascript that makes the request posts a JSON array in the same format that would be returned by a GET request

```
{
  "course":
  {
    "title":"US History",
    "credits":"3",
    "max_students":"100",
    "location":
    {
      "id":"",
      "building":"Freedom Hall",
      "room":"301"
    }
  }
}

or

{
  "course":
  {
    "title":"US History",
    "credits":"3",
    "max_students":"100",
    "location":
    {
      "id":"12", # this is the only difference
      "building":"Freedom Hall",
      "room":"301"
    }
  }
}
```

1. Compared with all of the examples I've read, this code doesn't look so elegant. Is there better way to factor it?
2. If Location.create raises an exception, will @course.save still be called? Do I need to use Location.create!?
3. Likewise, will validation errors end up in @course.errors even though the errors were on the Location model? Do I need to rescue from the exception so that I can return the errors to the client?

Thank you very much for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean that up by using `find_or_initialize_by_id`. This should work:

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(params[:course])
  @course.location = Location.find_or_initialize_by_id(params[:course][:location][:id],
                                                       params[:course][:location])
  @course.save
  respond_with @course
end
```

Regarding your second question, in your code as you have it `@course.save` will not be called if `Location.create` (or `Location.find`) raises an exception (because they would happen first). However, the way I have coded it above, the exception would happen at the same point in the code, when `save` is called, at which point the association is also saved.

Comment: Thank you! I was leaning toward something like this but I had cold feet. And you confirmed my suspicions about exception handling -- I just didn't know if anything was happening behind the scenes which might affect my expectations. Does this require adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location` to my Course model?

Comment: You're welcome. No AFAIK you shouldn't have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location` to do this since you're explicitly setting the attributes on the location. Although, if you had nested attributes I believe you would be able to initialize everything with just `@course = Course.new(params[:course])`, and the `location` attributes would be set automatically. Haven't tested that though so not sure whether it would work when the location `id` is set.

Comment: I'll need to write some tests, but once I do I'll add a comment with my findings. My fear is that if `id` is set on the nested location, but all other fields are empty, then rails would actually update the attributes on the matched location, setting them to empty (presuming that empty fields are valid), and save the record. That would result in wiping out the data in the location record. But I can't help but think that rails is smart enough to know what to do. Like I said, I'll reply again once I know how it actually works.

Comment: If the `id` is set and other fields are missing, they won't be overwritten. However if they are *blank* (e.g. `"building":""`) then yes, they will be overwritten, but that is expected behaviour, if you don't want to overwrite something just don't include it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in your controller

```
def new
  @course = Course.new 
  @location = @course.location.build # if one..many relationship
  @location = @course.build_location # if one..one relationship
end

def create
 @course = Course.new(params[:course])
 if @course.save
   respond_with @course
 else
   render :action => "new"
 end
end
```

more about [nested_attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What is the advantage of doing this, as opposed to using find_or_initialize_by_id? I need to learn more about nested models. I guess I hadn't connected the dots with this being related to nesting.